# Running Javascript after an MVC Ajax..BeginForm partial postback

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I've got the following scenario using ASP.NET MVC2

I have a partial view that uses an Ajax.BeginForm to allow a partial postback, with the OnSuccess property of the AjaxOptions pointing to the js function onPartialReloadSuccess. The updateTargetId is housed on a parent View "Application" as referenced in the BeginForm script.

This partial view itself renders a number of other partial views, the names of which are generated dynamically based on the model

```
<% using (Ajax.BeginForm("Application", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "mainframe", OnSuccess = "onPartialReloadSuccess" })) { %>

    <div id="breadcrumbs">
        <% Html.RenderPartial(Model.Breadcrumbs, Model);%>
    </div>

    <div id="action">
        <% Html.RenderPartial(Model.CurrentView, Model);%>
    </div>

<% } %>
```

My problem is as follows - after a partial postback the 'onPartialReloadSuccess' js function is successfully called without problem, *but* non of the javascript contained within the sub-views is re-run.

They were initially set up to run after a jQuery $(document).ready()... which obviously won't work on a partial postback

My question is this - is there any way to ensure that the javascript on these re-rendered partial views is run? I see a lot of solutions for asp.net forms (using scriptmanager and PageRequestManager), but nothing specific for ASP.NET MVC?

thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Doesn't work OOTB in ASP.NET MVC 3 since it uses jQuery AJAX (which magically runs JS in loaded content)? Then perhaps using jQuery AJAX could be an option for you as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could externalize those scripts into separate function(s) and then in the `onPartialReloadSuccess` function explicitly call this function(s). Also call them in the `document.ready` so that the initial load also works.

Answer (score 0):

looks like I found the answer I required at http://adammcraventech.wordpress.com/2010/06/11/asp-net-mvc2-ajax-executing-dynamically-loaded-javascript/ with the following quote explaining the problem

> I have been tinkering with ASP.NET MVC2 for a while and I had the problem where the MVC2 >Client Validation did not work when I was dynamically loading a partial view through MVC2 >AJAX. Upon further investigation, I discovered that the issue was not limited just to MVC2 >Client Validation, but to all JavaScript that is dynamically loaded through MVC2 AJAX. The >issue has to do with the way that the response is injected into the DOM element – through the >InnerHTML property. Any script block injected into that property will not be executed.